# react-native-navigation giving error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')"

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to navigate to the home page from login page but my login-form is in another folder named "component", When I'm navigating from the login page using touchableOpacity it is working, But when I'm doing same thing from login-form component it is giving me an error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code which I'm trying to perform.

**code of Login.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm';

type Props = {};
export default class Login extends Component<Props> {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                    <LoginForm/>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text> Skip login and goto</Text>
                    <Text onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
                        Home
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

**code of LoginForm.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class LoginForm extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={'Email'}
                    keyboardType={'email-address'}
                    autoCapitalize={'none'}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.6}
                    onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                >
                    <Text>
                        Home
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

here is the screenshot of error:
**[Error when navigating to page in another folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJGq1.jpg)**

Please help me to get out of this error. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you share Navigation code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withNavigation` or you should pass navigation as a props to child component.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

type Props = {};
 class LoginForm extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={'Email'}
                    keyboardType={'email-address'}
                    autoCapitalize={'none'}
                />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.6}
                    onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                >
                    <Text>
                        Home
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default withNavigation(LoginForm);
```

Comment: Thanks..!!
It worked for me...

Can you do me one more favor, can you tell me any tutorials for react-native and react-native-navigation, I'm new at react native and I watched videos on YouTube but not understood properly. So can you suggest any tutorial from scratch to moderate level app developing in react native.

Answer (score 0):

In the end of your LoginForm.js you need to put `export {LoginForm};`

If only this not work, try make your import like this: import {LoginForm} from '../components/LoginForm';

Comment: I already exported LoginForm as `export default class LoginForm `.